# Google admob specific interstitial ads are not closing

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

In my app I implemented interstitial ads.

On adclose my content will load.

I used following code for implementing this

```
    if (MainActivity.interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        MainActivity.interstitialAd.show();

        MainActivity.interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(youtubeVideoId, 0);
            }
        });
    } else {
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(youtubeVideoId, 0);
    }

    MainActivity.loadInterstitialAd();
```

This implementation works on interstitial ads before.

But, from yesterday i discovered some specific ads which are not closing.

I think the problem is from google admob api but how can I fix the issue in my end?

Comment: It's been reported and they are [investigating it](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/t8Ln93xvi3g). But I don't think they are gonna fix it anytime soon.

Answer (score 2):

This bug is from June 2020 but all Google employees are work from home..  Lots of publishers and developers are posted in various platforms they are not responding. I think Google was not serious on this type of bugs. They only suspend admob, AdSense if anything went wrong. If the bug is from their side we can only do just need to wait for lifetime until they woke up from sleep.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/issues/272